# MATLAB: Pass class function handle to ode45()?

Tags: matlab, oop, function-handle

I have a class function that uses ODE45 to solve some equations.  I have another, private class function that represents the odefunction that ODE45 needs to solve.  However, I can't figure out how to pass a handle of the class's ode function to ODE45.  Here is the sample code:

```
class ODESolver < handle

    methods (Access = public)

        function obj = RunODE(obj, t, y0)
            [~, Z] = ode45(@ODEFunction, t, y0);
        end

    end

    methods (Access = private)

        function dy = ODEFunction(t,y)
            % Calculate dy here.
        end

    end

end
```

When I run this, i get an error saying:

```
Undefined function 'ODEFunction' for input arguments of type 'double'.
```

If I move ODEFunction outside of the class and put it in its own *.m file, the code runs fine.  I've also tried using "@obj.ODEFunction" in the ode45 call, but then it says:

```
Too many input arguments.
```

What's the best way to keep ODEFunction inside of my class and still be able to pass it's handle to ode45?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your private `ODEFunction` is not a static method, so you should write:

```
classdef ODESolver < handle

    methods (Access = public)

        function obj = RunODE(obj, t, y0)
            [~, Z] = ode45(@(tt, yy)obj.ODEFunction(tt, yy), t, y0);
        end

    end

    methods (Access = private)

        function dy = ODEFunction(obj, t,y)
            dy = 0.1; % Calculate dy here.
        end

    end

end
```

NB: You also forgot to pass `obj` as first argument of private `ODEFunction` ... I'm writing example with static method and will paste it here once tested.

**Edit**

Here is how you should write things if you intented to have private static `ODEFunction` in your class:

```
classdef ODESolver < handle

    methods (Access = public)

        function obj = RunODE(obj, t, y0)
            [~, Z] = ode45(@(tt, yy)ODESolver.ODEFunction(tt, yy), t, y0);
        end

    end

    methods (Static, Access = private)

        function dy = ODEFunction(t,y)
            dy = 0.1; % Calculate dy here.
        end

    end

end
```

Comment: Awesome, will try this out after lunch.  What is the significance of (tt, yy)?

Comment: This is syntaxic sugar to ease readiness. Personnally, when I write an anonymous method I prefer to write `@(*parameters as passed by the caller*)MyFunction(*parameters that i want to effectively pass to MyFunction*)` .... this also works with `varargin` and local scope variables: `@(varargin)MyFunction(localScopeVariable, varargin{end:-1:1})`

Comment: Here is also more details for why to use `@MyClass.MyMethod` with static methods and `@obj.MyMethod` (or `@(varargin)MyMethod(obj, varargin{:})` ) with non static ones : http://fr.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_oop/class-methods-for-graphics-callbacks.html

Comment: Thanks for all the info.  Just tried it out, works like a charm!

Comment: U're welcome ... You'll see, writing anonymous function becomes easier with time ... ;)